# Improving readability of black and white map

Tags: qgis, symbology, visualisation, color-ramp

[image]

I need to produce a map using grayscale (QGIS), as this figure will be printed in black and white.

The map is made up of two layers:

- one cointains the polygon geometry (land cover) - there are five different land cover classes
- one contains the point geometry (facilities) - there are two different attributes, placed on the polygons of the land cover.
  They advised me to choose two different symbols for the facilities, I opted for the star and the triangle. But when I have to choose the typology of gray for these 7 different elements (5 land cover classes; 2 point attributes), no solution seems to be enough nice to me.

Do you have any advice?

The biggest challenges is to identify two grays for the point layer which are enough visible.

after receiving your tips the new map - closeup - is[image]

Comment: You did not make it clear what exactly the issue is for you and without visual examples it is hard to guess what your map might look like. For the points you mention two different types but then 7 different ones?

Comment: 5 land cover classes  (polygon)+  2 attributes (points)

Comment: Daniel Huffman did a monochrome mapping competition, a look at the result may give you some idea : https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/monocarto-2019-winners/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just some ideas, not a final solution:

- use grey scale fills for your polygon legend, no colors, since then you have more control over the conversion
- don't use black fills either for symbols nor for the fills
- use "Draw Effects" like "outer glow" for your point symbols to highlight them against the background - see pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your map looks very nice! I tried to follow your tips, I would say that the map has improved, except for the fact there is a white shadow due to the outer glow effect. I'll attach a figure to my main question.

Answer (score 2):

### Styling polygons: Different fill styles

- Dense (1 to 7)
- Horizontal/Vertical/Diagonal/Cross line patterns (see first screenshot)
- Point Patterns
- Gradient Fill (use grey instead of black)

Each of those with different settings for line spacing/width, point distance/size etc.

[image]

### Styling Points: combined symbols

Use combined symbols (like star and circle) with a point in the middle and be sure to make the outline visible engough for contrast.

*Screenshot to demonstrate the principle. Implementation is not yet perfect:*
[image]

*How the legend looks like:*

[image]